# In Clojurescript how can I use multiple symbols or macros?

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

To "use" symbols in Clojurescript I often find myself having huge headers in clojurescript files, something like this:

```
  (:use-macros
   [webapp.framework.client.coreclient      :only  [defn-ui-component ns-coils write-ui read-ui]])

  (:use
   [webapp.framework.client.coreclient      :only  [log amend-record  component-fn write-ui-fn]]))
```

:but I would like to have something more compact like in Clojure, so that I can just have:

```
  (:use-macros [webapp.framework.client.coreclient])
  (:use [webapp.framework.client.coreclient]))
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not supported and it seems that [it won't be supported](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/clojurescript/SzYK08Oduxo). "use" is considered a bad practice both in Clojure and ClojureScript as it makes the code less readable.